# Alter multiple tables using single query?

Tags: mysql

Can I alter **MULTIPLE TABLES** using a single query? If so, what's the correct syntax for that?

I have already tried:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 ADD (name VARCHAR (50), age DATETIME)
ALTER TABLE tbl2 ADD (name VARCHAR (50), age DATETIME)
```

Comment: You can not Alter multiple tables in single query.

Comment: Is there any way that I can do such?

Comment: you have to prepare one query for each one.

Comment: good question, I don't understand the downvotes

Answer (score 3):

As per the [MySQL doco](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html), `alter table` only allows you to alter *one* table at a time:

```
ALTER [ONLINE | OFFLINE] [IGNORE] TABLE tbl_name
    [alter_specification [, alter_specification] ...]
    [partition_options]
```

There is no provision in there for multiple `TABLE tbl_name` clauses, so you'll need *two* distinct `alter table` commands.

Of course, if you use external tooling (like `bash`) to run your commands, there's nothing stopping you from doing something like:

```
for tbl in tbl1 tbl2 ; do
    mysql --user=pax \
          --password=never_you_mind \
          --execute="alter table ${tbl} add (name varchar(50), age datetime)"
done
```

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right, I didn't see that section in the doco. I'll remove that concern but it doesn't change the basic problem which is that you cannot do mutiple tables at once.